# Why the author choose $s$ real?

Tags: elliptic-curves

My question is: Why the author of this book (http://wstein.org/books/bsd/bsd.pdf) page 8 on Sec 1.4 choose $s$ real in despite that the variable is complex in the entire chapter. I am very confused about this fact.

Comment: "See [Dok04] for a more sophisticated analysis of computing $L(E, s)$ and its Taylor expansion for any complex number $s$." Computing for real $s$ is simpler, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture is about the value of $L(s,E)$ at $s=1$, so real valued is even more general.

Comment: Birch! With a B!

Comment: Thanks, of coure BSD conjecture not DSD:-)

Comment: Correct. While I am nitpicking, it should be the "Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture", instead of "Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer". The latter seems to imply three people, while only two people are being credited, Bryan Birch and Sir H. P. F. Swinnerton-Dyer.